# Sql;select average and one value from same column

Tags: sql-server, select, average

How can I get an average value and one other value from the same column into two different columns in a new table?

I have this:

```
Person_ID col2         col3_values
1         101010A      20000
1         101010B      30000
2         101010A      25000
2         101010B      30000
3         101010A      22000
3         101010B      24000
```

And I want a table that average col3_values with ID:s from col1_ID (1,2,3) and then compare this average value with a column wich holds the col1_ID: value like this:

```
col2        AVG(value personID_1-3)  Value PersonID_1
101010 A    22333                    20000
101010 B    28000                    30000
```

I have tried a lot of code but nothing had worked. Can someone please help me with this? If this worked I would be grateful if I also could get a fourth column thay show the difference between the averagecolumn and the third column that hold ID_1:s values.

Comment: I don't think you've supplied enough information about how the values are calculated. I tried but couldn't figure out the significance of the third column.

Comment: The third column (Value PersonID_1) is from Person_ID =1 from the first column i the first table where 101010A= 20000 and 101010B=30000 The average is PersonID1-3 for 101010A (20000+25000+22000)/3 and for 101010B  (30000+30000+24000)/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many ways to do this, one would be to use the `outer apply` construct:

```
select 
    col2, 
    AVG(t.col3_values) as "AVG(value personID_1-3)", 
    a.col3_values as "Value PersonID_1",
    AVG(t.col3_values) - a.col3_values as "Difference"
from your_table t 
outer apply (
    select col3_values from your_table  where Person_ID = 1 and t.col2 = col2
) a
group by col2, a.col3_values
```

Or you could use a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    col2, 
    AVG(t.col3_values) as "AVG(value personID_1-3)", 
    (
      select col3_values from your_table where Person_ID = 1 and t.col2 = col2
    ) as "Value PersonID_1"
from your_table t 
group by col2
```

Sample output:

```
Query 1:
col2                 AVG(value personID_1-3) Value PersonID_1 Difference
-------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- -----------
101010A              22333                   20000            2333
101010B              28000                   30000            -2000


Query 2:    
col2                 AVG(value personID_1-3) Value PersonID_1
-------------------- ----------------------- ----------------
101010A              22333                   20000
101010B              28000                   30000
```